# Map Firebase array into a list Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

What I want to do is make firebase array fields to a list in flutter. As you see in the first picture that is the array named items and in it there are 2 field values, I want to put those field values in a list as you see on the second picture.

[field value array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD8Zf.png)
[List tile to have each of the field values on there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeMdP.png)

Comment: Are you sure those are the images you want us to see?  It's really not clear what you're asking right now.

Comment: Those field values of the array I want to take them and put them on a list format

Comment: Those two photos are the same, could you give some more info/code/models on the data you are trying to retrieve, and I should be able to help you understand.

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to put the other photo

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc("dwq").snapshots().listen((doc) {
      items = [ for(var item in doc.get("items")) item as String ];
});
```

If you don't want to listen to changes, use `get()` instead of `snapshots()`.

Comment: should I put in a future builder

Comment: So how should I put it

Comment: Generally, you want to use that in your [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) solution.